# how to decompile user password in django

Tags: python, django, sha1

I have a SECRET_KEY,
how do i decompile a user password using python?
I assume that the encryption method is sha1.
thanks.

Comment: I don't really think you can "decompile" it, but you could try to bruteforce it using some program like cain and abel?

Comment: Never heard of hsa1, what is it? If you mean *sha1*, that's not an encryption method, it's a hashing algorithm.

Comment: I think he means sha1 since that's the tag.

Comment: So much work has been put into the non-decompilability of sha1 and now we should break it just for a few upvotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking the impossible.  The passwords are salted and hashed.  The way they're validated is by performing the same process on the re-supplied password.  There's no way to 'decrypt' it.